# How can an app know it has the permission to enter autonomous single app mode(ASAM)?

Tags: ios, mdm

I know that an app can enter autonomous single app mode when MDM server grants it using "autonomousSingleAppModePermittedAppIDs". 
I'm thinking that whether there is a way for an app to find it's whitelisted. Consider that my app is already running for a long time, then MDM server whitelist it, how can my app know that? Is there any notification? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There are two things:
1. Single app mode
2. Whitelist of applications

If you want to implement single app mode , then you will apply payload and app automatically enters into single app mode (device must be supervised).

If you want to whitelist apps then you have to apply payload which contains bundle identifiers of whitelist apps(device must be supervised).

Now answer for your question is that your app will not listen to the commands which will send by MDM server. It will listen by device and take action according to command.

Comment: What I want to use is Autonomous Single App Mode. The app will have the ability to enter or exit single app mode by itself if MDM server give it the permission. It's different from Single App Mode configured by the MDM server directly. And now I have the answer that app can't know whether it's whitelisted. Thanks!